# Calling fragment from another fragment issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Android , I have a `Fragment` in which I have a `Button` and on the Button click I want to display another `Fragment` in place of this `Fragment` in the same Activity. My code for changing `Fragment` is like this:

```
 btnMainSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment generateRequistionFrag=new generate_material_requisition();

                if (generateRequistionFrag != null) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_container, generateRequistionFrag).commit();

                }
            }
        });
```

I am getting error like this:

```
  Process: kanix.highrise.com.highrise, PID: 3427
    java.lang.ClassCastException: kanix.highrise.com.highrise.MainActivity@3992b1e7 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
            at kanix.highrise.com.highrise.generate_material_requisition.onAttach(generate_material_requisition.java:83)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:853)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
```

I tried to implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener` but not working.

My full fragment code from where I want to switch to other fragement is like this:

```
 * Created by Mubashir.gul on 13/05/2015.
 */
public class MaterialRequisition extends Fragment {
    Spinner drpProj,drpMaterial,drpTask;
    ProgressDialog pbar;
    private ImageButton btncal;
    private Calendar cal;
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;
    private EditText etcal;

    EditText etQuantity,etSrProject,etSrMaterial,etSrTask;
    List<CItem> lstItm;
    CItem Itm;
    Activity myactivity;
    Button btnSearchProject,btnSearchMaterial,btnSearchTask,btnMainSearch;
    String ProID,MatrID,TaskID;
    public MaterialRequisition(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_material_requisition, container, false);
//code for calender
        btncal = (ImageButton)rootView. findViewById(R.id.btnimgcal);

        etcal = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etDate);
        etcal.setKeyListener(null);//setting edittext non editable
        etQuantity = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etQuantity);
        drpProj = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drpProject);
        drpMaterial = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drpMaterial);
        drpTask = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drpTask);
        btnSearchProject =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSearchProject);
        btnSearchMaterial =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSearchMaterial );
        btnSearchTask =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSearchTask );
        btnMainSearch=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnMainSearch);

        etSrProject=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etSearchProject);
        etSrMaterial=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etSearchMaterial);
        etSrTask=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.etSearchTask);
        myactivity=this.getActivity();//getting parent activity in a variable for use in async task
        etQuantity.setKeyListener(null);//setting edittext non editable


//loading projects
        btnSearchProject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                ProjectAsync PAsync=new ProjectAsync();
                PAsync.execute(etSrProject.getText().toString());
            }
        });







      btnSearchMaterial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              if (!drpProj.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select Project") ) {

                  MaterialAsync MAsync = new MaterialAsync();
                  MAsync.execute("64");
              }
              else
              {

                  Toast.makeText(myactivity,"Please select project first!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

              }
          }
      });

        btnSearchTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!drpProj.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select Project") ) {

                    ListTaskAsync taskasync = new ListTaskAsync();
                    taskasync.execute(ProID);
                }
                else
                {

                    Toast.makeText(myactivity,"Please select project first!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                }
            }
        });



        btnMainSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment generateRequistionFrag=new generate_material_requisition();

                if (generateRequistionFrag != null) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_container, generateRequistionFrag).commit();

                }
            }
        });






        btncal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
            }
        });
//code for calender







       //call to async task

        lstItm=new ArrayList<CItem>();
        Itm=new CItem( "-1", "Select Project" );
        lstItm.add(Itm);
        if(lstItm.size()>0) {
            ArrayAdapter<CItem> adapterProj = new ArrayAdapter<CItem>(myactivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstItm);

            drpProj.setAdapter(adapterProj);
        }





        lstItm=new ArrayList<CItem>();
        Itm=new CItem( "-1", "Select Material" );
        lstItm.add(Itm);

        if(lstItm.size()>0) {
            ArrayAdapter<CItem> adapterMater = new ArrayAdapter<CItem>(myactivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstItm);

            drpMaterial.setAdapter(adapterMater);
        }

        lstItm=new ArrayList<CItem>();
        Itm=new CItem( "-1", "Select Task" );
        lstItm.add(Itm);

        if(lstItm.size()>0) {
            ArrayAdapter<CItem> adapterMater = new ArrayAdapter<CItem>(myactivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstItm);

            drpTask.setAdapter(adapterMater);
        }


        drpProj.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             //  if (drpMaterial.getCount() > 0)
             //      drpMaterial.setAdapter(null);
               if (!drpProj.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select Project"))
               {

                   MaterialAsync MAsync=new MaterialAsync();
                   MAsync.execute("64");

               }


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        //loading task list




        Button btnSave=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {





                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Saving please wait!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Saved successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });







        //getting selected project
        drpProj.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                CItem itm=(CItem)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                ProID=itm.getId();



            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }




        });

        drpMaterial.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

            });


        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: you do'nt need to implement OnFragmentInteractionListener for a replace(). What about new generate_material_requisition()??

Comment: That is my question how to implement it and where to implement it.

Comment: My answer is that you don't have to implement it, can please post the code of your Fragments?

Comment: Show us your imports from fragments and your main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fragment generateRequistionFrag=new generate_material_requisition();
```

That's not the right way to get a new instance of your fragment so please remove

```
new generate_material_requisition()
```

Please in your Fragment class create a method getInstance() that return a new YouFragment instance

```
public static YourFragment getInstance() {
    return new Yourfragment;
}
```

and then when you need a new instance of that simply make:

```
YourFragment  fragment = YourFragment.getInstance()
```

Answer (score 0):

That interface should be implemented on the activity like

```
MainActivity extends Activity implements "Interface_Name"{
// and give the actual implementation of method OnFragmentInteractionListener
}
```

Now what your problem is i guess you are not initailising the variable properly , provide more code so that we can have insight on it and help you !

Also go to your onAttach method of fragment and comment it out for a try because i dont see you are using this call back any where , this might help you too !

Answer (score -2):

You need to replace

```
Fragment generateRequistionFrag=new generate_material_requisition();
```

for

```
 generate_material_requisition generateRequistionFrag=new generate_material_requisition();
```